# Highcharts "shared" tooltip gets ignored when tooltip is triggered via keyboard (thru accessibility module)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, accessibility

The Highcharts JS library has an accessibility module that allows you to activate the tooltip via your keyboard, but the "shared" option is ignored and a multi-point tooltip becomes a single point tooltip.

```
var chartOptions1 = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'column-chart-1'
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'percent'
        }
    },
    accessibility: {
        enabled: true
    },  
    series: seriesData
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/richfinelli/xme65xj3/25/

[image]

Is there a way to have the keyboard navigation display all data points in the tooltip. Or make the focus go from a single data point to all data points.

Comment: I see that you posted this as a **bug on github**. Here's a link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7261 so that everybody could follow this topic.